# Sqlite3 two conditions in one trigger for initcap

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I would like to ask you for a help. I have two trigger after insert, which check the insert of name and surname. If the name or surname start with small letter, trigger change name and surname to right format. Is it possible to make one trigger from this two triggers?

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_first_letter1
AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS
WHEN (SUBSTR(NEW.name,1,1) = LOWER(SUBSTR(NEW.name,1,1)))  BEGIN
    UPDATE MEMBERS SET NAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.name,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.name,2,10)))) WHERE ID=NEW.ID;
    END;


CREATE TRIGGER check_first_letter2
AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS
WHEN (SUBSTR(NEW.surname,1,1) = LOWER(SUBSTR(NEW.surname,1,1)))  BEGIN
    UPDATE MEMBERS SET SURNAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.surname,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.surname,2,10)))) WHERE ID=NEW.ID;
    END;
```

Comment: Yes (with WHERE), but why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will do what you wish :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_first_letter1
AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MEMBERS SET NAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.name,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.name,2,10)))) 
       WHERE ID=NEW.ID AND (SUBSTR(NEW.name,1,1) = LOWER(SUBSTR(NEW.name,1,1)));
    UPDATE MEMBERS SET SURNAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.surname,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.surname,2,10)))) 
        WHERE ID=NEW.ID AND (SUBSTR(NEW.surname,1,1) = LOWER(SUBSTR(NEW.surname,1,1)));
END
```

i.e.

- if **f**red and Bloggs is inserted the Trigger changes them to **F**red and Bloggs.
- if Fred and **bloggs** is inserted the Trigger changes them to Fred and **B**loggs.
- if **f**red **b**loggs is inserted the Trigger changes them to **F**red and **B**loggs.

However, the following simpler trigger would do the same :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_first_letter_always
AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MEMBERS SET  
            NAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.name,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.name,2,10)))),
            SURNAME=(select (UPPER(substr(NEW.surname,1,1))||LOWER(substr(NEW.surname,2,10))))
        WHERE ID=NEW.ID;
END;
```